# for-comprehension: type mismatch - required Option[?]

Tags: scala, type-mismatch, for-comprehension

I am relatively new to using Scala in a project and stumbled over a problem I just don't understand.

This is my code. I annotated types for clarity:

```
val fcs = for {
      fc: Call <- funCalls
      ann: List[CapabilityArg] <- context.annotationOption(Annotations.CapabilityArguments, fc)
      arg: CapabilityArg <- ann
} yield CapabilityInfo(
      "CapabilityArgument", arg.id.name, new LSPRange, new LSPRange
)
```

which errors with:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : List[LSPServer.this.CapabilityInfo]
 required: Option[?]
```

If if remove the last line in the for-comprehension, the error disappears. Shouldn't that line be okay, since I only map over a List[CapabilityArg]?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are the types of `funCalls` and `annotationOption`?

Comment: @Dima funCalls is of type Vector[Call] and the annotationOption returns an Option[List[CapabilityArg]]

Tim's answer pretty much solved my issue, tho :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing `List` and `Option` in the `for`. The result collection type of a `for` is the collection type of the first line, which I assume is `Option`. The last line in the `for` will generate multiple values but `Option` can only hold one value.

This is probably what you want:

```
val fcs = for {
  fc: Call <- funCalls
  ann: List[CapabilityArg] <- context.annotationOption(Annotations.CapabilityArguments, fc)
} yield {
  ann.map(arg => CapabilityInfo(
    "CapabilityArgument", arg.id.name, new LSPRange, new LSPRange
  ))
}
```

This will return `Option[List[CapabilityInfo]]`

Comment: Maybe what OP wants is just to flatten everything into a `List`?

Comment: If you want it flattened into a `List`, you can just add `.toList` to the return of `funCalls`

Comment: Thank you @Tim, it never came to my mind to add a block after yield and work with `ann` from there.
As mentioned above, funCalls is of type Vector[Call] and the annotationOption returns an Option[List[CapabilityArg]]. So what I am trying to do is get each List[CapabilityArg] from each Call in funcalls. Then, for each CapabilityArg in the resulting list I want to construct a CapabilityInfo.
See the edit of my post :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @[Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7662670/tim) I came up with this solution:

```
val fcs = for {
      fc: Call <- funCalls : Array[Call]
      ann: List[CapabilityArg] <- context.annotationOption(Annotations.CapabilityArguments, fc) : Option[List[CapabilityArg]]
} yield {
      ann.toArray.map(arg =>
        CapabilityInfo("CapabilityArgument", arg.id.name, new LSPRange, new LSPRange)
      )
}

return fcs.flatten
```

I switched funCalls to type Array[Call] so I yield an Array[CapabilityInfo] that is then packed into another array. The result is then flattened to give me the desired one-dimensional array of all CapabilityInfos.

In hindsight I probably should have gone for a regular nested for-each construct?!